# stageros tf frame names

Tags: simulation, stage, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to change the tf frame names from the stageros node?

I could use the tf_remap, but it is not  useful in this case because the default names are being used for other propose and I need to avoid collisions in the data sent to /tf

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243479/stageros-tf-frame-names/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2016-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks it is not implemented.

I directly implemented it and I have sent a pull request to the stage_ros git repository:

https://github.com/ros-simulation/stage_ros/pull/38

Applying this pull request it is directly possible to change the values of the frames through the local parameters called:

"odom_frame_id", "base_frame_id", "base_frame_footprint_id" and "base_laser_frame_id"

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2016-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1